# Ruby on rails multi app website?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a question about ruby on rails. If i want to build a website with four main menus on the front page with blog, news, highlights and information, and each of them is their seperate app. How do i start building it? Do i build it one app at a time and combine them later or I can build them as one app?

I have only learnt how to build single rails apps, this seems like a very basic questions but I have not thought about this when learning rails. For example, the dominos home page, each of the headings on the top row, how would I handle them when building a rails app?

Comment: Your apps are not going to be "conscious" of each other. Simplest solution is to create a gem which contains the navigation and include it in each rails app. Another potential solution is to use a single rails app and make each section a mountable engine. But do you really need it? Are you really solving any real problems by spreading this out into 4 apps or just adding a bunch of complexity?

Comment: I am sort of adding a bunch of complexity, because for each heading, there are going to be different content in each one, i dont know any other way to do it, for example , the first one only has title,text,description, the second one only have video, the third one only have posts, what is the easiest way to build it out like this?